# Increment operation in cshtml

Tags: sql, razor, asp.net-webpages

I want to increment the value of an attribute on click of a button i.e when a user clicks a button, the value of the attribute (int) would be increased by 1.

This is my code to increase the value:

```
if(IsPost){
    if(Request["like"] == forum_topic_id){
        //get the value of the forum post id from the button
        forumpostid = Request.Form["like"]; 
        var likepostcommand = "UPDATE forum_post SET forum_post_up = forum_post_up + 1 WHERE forum_post_id = @0";
        var likepostdata = db.Query(likepostcommand, forumpostid);
    }
}
```

The `button` to trigger this operation is:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="like" value="@getforumtopicdetailsdata.forum_thread_id">Like</button>
```

The button is inside a form.

On click of the button, the value of the attribute `forum_post_up` should increase by a value `1`.

Any help?

Comment: you can use ajax call to accomplish this task

Comment: can you please explain how? @HirenKagrana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
if(IsPost){
    if(Convert.ToInt32(Request["like"]) == forum_topic_id){
        //get the value of the forum post id from the button
        forumpostid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["like"]); 
        var likepostcommand = @"UPDATE forum_post SET forum_post_up = forum_post_up + 1 
            WHERE forum_post_id = @0";
        var likepostdata = db.Execute(likepostcommand, forumpostid);
    }
}
```

Pay attention that `Request["like"]` and `Request.Form["like"]` accomplish the same result: return the "like" value (so I don't really understand the meaning of your code).

Comment: The code doesn't increment any value in the database. I don't get to know how! On click of the button, the value of `forum_post_up` should increment by a value `1`. Is the query `set forum_post_up = forum_post_up + 1` correct in cshtm?

Comment: Are you sure that `Convert.ToInt32(Request["like"]) == forum_topic_id` is true? Add `<p>@forumpostid</p>` after `forumpostid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["like"]);`. If the if condition is true, at the beginning of your page you should see the value of forumpostid. Verify that there is a valid forum_post_id in your table that matches its value.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Actually I was doing mistake somewhere else! @gmg